# why does following code give different output in C , C++?

Tags: c++, c

The following code gives output as
1, 4, 4 in C whereas 
1, 1, 4 in C++

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{  
    char ch = 'A'; //initialise 
    //printing output
    printf("%d, %d, %d", sizeof(ch), sizeof('A'), sizeof(3.14f));    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: look http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-54/

Comment: but its not at stackoverflow i searched it here at stackoverflow n didn't found any similar one. well i got the answer thts important for me. thank you

Comment: `i searched it here at stackoverflow n didn't found any similar one`. dont understand. is stackoverflow answer different then that one?

Comment: no but that is at geeksforgeeks.org n people are marking this one as duplicate , i thought you are also amongst them that's why

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because a character literal is of type `int` in C but of type `char` in C++.